# Apex Class Unit Test for PartnerNetworkConnection and PartnerNetworkRecordConnection without SeeAllData=true

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

Is there a way to create unit testing for `PartnerNetworkConnection` and `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` without using live data(SeeAllData=true)?

I've been having a lot of issues trying to deploy S2S Apex unit code without using live data. I can't seem to modify any fields in those two Partner Network Connection objects. The only way I've been able to deploy to production from Sandbox is to populate production with a bunch of dummy data to pass the test.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf), those objects can only be created. You can't update any of those records. If I'm not mistaken, you first need to enable Salesforce to Salesforce in your org, then deploy your S2S Apex classes to support it just as you do with other Salesforce features such as Sites.